# How to Query Data with better speed?

Tags: mysql, backgroundworker

I beg the idea to handle query data with better speed. Already tried using, index or Store Procedures, but still often do not get the value of the data (the data some time empty).

Table (tbl_Phonebook) contains thousands of data that contains the phone number and name of the owner of the phone.

### Thank You

This is MyCode:

```
Private Sub FrmLogger_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Interval = 50
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    'check data (phonenumber) in ChannelData

    For i = 0 To 31 'length of objChannelData
        If objChannelData(i) <> "" Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells.Item(1).Value() = objChannelData(i) 'the value is PhoneNumber 
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells.Item(2).Value() = GetPhoneBookName(objChannelData(i)) ' try to get Name of PhoneNumber owner  
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Function GetPhoneBookName(ByVal nPhoneNumber As String) As String
    'check db connection
    Try
        If (Conn_MySQL.State = ConnectionState.Closed) Then
            Conn_MySQL.Open()
        End If
        'get value from table 
        Dim strSQL As String = "select fPhoneName from tbl_Phonebook where fPhoneNumber = '" & nPhoneNumber & "'"
        Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand(strSQL, Conn_MySQL)
        Dim myReader As MySqlDataReader
        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
        myReader.Read()

        If myReader.HasRows Then
            If Not IsDBNull(myReader.GetValue(0)) Then
                Return myReader.GetString(0)
            Else
                Return ""
            End If
            myReader.Close()
        Else
            Return ""
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ""
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: The problem might be the format of the phone numbers. Just about everywhere I have worked has had little or no validation on phone number entries. So the numbers would sometimes have spaces, hyphens, and/or periods as separators. They would sometimes have the area code. Sometimes the area code would be in parentheses.

Comment: Hi @CptMisery,
I've made sure that the data on objChannelData (n) are valid and clean. The character or string that is not needed is already disposed.
The current allegations, the process of query output gives the desired late (> 50milisecond).
Read some of the discussion process of query data, some programmers use a backgroundworker to ensure query process can be done satisfaction without impeding the other process.
Could it be that with the backgroundworker may be the solution for my case? I know there is a function of the Backgroundworker, and still confused to use it. THKS.

Comment: Yesterday must have been a long day for me. For some reason I thought you were having issues getting data. In your DB, do you have an index on fPhoneNumber?

Comment: @CptMisery Yes, i have index on fPhoneNumber.

Comment: You could try creating the database connection in `timer1_tick` and pass it to the `GetPhoneBookName` function. That would cut down on the number of times you have to make a connection.

Comment: You could also make `GetPhoneBookName` function accept an array of phone numbers. You can then use the array to search for all the phone numbers at the same time.